# How To Set Server Output On in DataGrip

Tags: sql, oracle, datagrip

How Can I "**set server output**" on in Jetbrains DataGrip IDE? I am able to do this in SQL Developer and run the SQL script successfully. The same script I try to run in DataGrip and it gives error. I know its the "**set server output on**" that is not working because I had to configure SQL Developer for it to work. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about datagrip, but isn't it `set serveroutput on` without the space?

Answer (score 49):

[According to the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2016.3/writing-and-executing-sql-statements.html#d115644e516):

> For Oracle, you can enable or disable showing the contents of the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer in the output pane. To do that, use [image: button] on the toolbar of the Database Console tool window (<kbd>Ctrl+F8</kbd>).

They also show an image of the window with the button enabled;

[image: 2]

**Update: 2019**

The icon to enable the output looks like:

[image]

On MacOS it can be enabled with Command+F8.

Comment: Your top screenshot is from version 2016, while I have version 2018.3 (built Nov 27, 2018) and I cannot see this option. In file window, I don't have option to enable output, in "Database Console" I don't have this option. And I have a official version, registered in company I work for.

Answer (score 2):

Server output is client side functionality that not all clients support.  SQL*Plus and SQL Developer do, but it's not a given that any other client will.

The SQL*Plus client command `set serveroutput on` essentially calls the `DBMS_OUTPUT.enable()` stored procedure on your behalf.  Additionally it signals to the client that is should inspect the `DBMS_OUTPUT.get_lines()` procedure for cached output after each code block is executed.

If DataGrip doesn't do this already, you may be able to manually code the calls to `DBMS_OUTPUT.enable()` and `DBMS_OUTPUT.get_lines()` as needed.

Comment: I had to call DBMS_OUTPUT.enable(); (at least for once) explicitly between BEGIN and END

Answer (score 2):

For version `2021.1` right click on the console list in the service window and there should be a enable `DBMS_OUTPUT` when you right click.

Comment: still true for version 2023.1